# Duplicate entry for key 'PRIMARY' using JPA to persist into database

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

I have an error with JPA persisting into my database, the error occurs when i persist a second file into the DB. I have a requirement to import numerous datasets, with 5 sheets each. There is a requirement to update each table even if some of the same data is already in there. At the moment i get the following error

**Error**

```
17:26:35,315 WARN  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) SQL Error: 1062, SQLState: 23000
17:26:35,316 ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

**Database Script**

My script to create the DB is as follows:

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS sampleDB;



use sampleDB;



CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Table1`(`mcc` int(10) NOT NULL,`mnc` int(10) NOT NULL,`operator` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,`country` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY (`mcc`,`mnc`))ENGINE=InnoDB;



CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Table2`(`tac` int(10) NOT NULL,`marketingName` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,`manufacturer` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,

    `accessCapability` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,`model` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,`vendorName` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,

    `ueType` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,`os` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,`inputMode` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,PRIMARY KEY (`tac`))ENGINE=InnoDB;



CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Table3`(`causeClass` varchar(10) NOT NULL,`description` varchar(255) NOT NULL,PRIMARY KEY (`causeClass`))ENGINE=InnoDB;



CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Table4`(`causeCode` int(5) NOT NULL,`eventId` int(5) NOT NULL,`description` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY (`causeCode`,`eventId`) ON UPDATE NO ACTION))ENGINE=InnoDB;



CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Table5`(`baseDataTableId` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,`dateTime` DATETIME NOT NULL,`eventId` int(5) NOT NULL,`causeClass` varchar(10) NOT NULL,

  `ueType` int(15) NOT NULL,`market` int(10) NOT NULL,`operator` int(10) NOT NULL,`cellId` tinyint(2) DEFAULT NULL,`duration` smallint(7) DEFAULT NULL,

  `causeCode` int(5) NOT NULL,`neVersion` varchar(7) DEFAULT NULL,`imsi` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,`hier3Id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,`hier32Id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,

  `hier321Id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,PRIMARY KEY (`baseDataTableId`))ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

**Java Hibernate properties**

My Hibernate properties are as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0"
   xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
   <persistence-unit name="primary">
      <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/MySqlDS</jta-data-source>
      <properties>
         <!-- Properties for Hibernate -->
         <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
         <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
         <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
         <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="false" />
      </properties>
   </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

**Java**

Entity Class example:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Table3")
public class Table3 {

        @Id
        private int causeClass;
        private String description;

        public Table3(){}

        public Table3(int causeClass, String description) {
            super();
            this.causeClass = causeClass;
            this.description = description;
        }

        // getters & setters

}
```

Any ideas how to solve this problem?

Comment: Can't see your entity classes here. Are the id properties annotated with `@GeneratedValue`? do you mean to set it yourself?

Comment: I have one table where i set the "@GeneratedValue" myself with autoIncrement and that works fine (I can see the results updating in mysql workbench) - i will put up an example of one of the entities that are failing now -

Comment: You should add `@GeneratedValue` to `private int causeClass;`, unless you call the constructor `public Table3(int causeClass, String description)` which lets you set manually the id property

Comment: I dont think im allowed to do that - the causeClass value given to me is read in from an excel file which i go through with apache poi and persist to the database - so i dont generate it, i tried it in any with no luck

Comment: Does this error happen when you try to persist any record or only with some records? It seems to me that some of your entities does not have any causeClass, therefore java will assign default int value (0), when it happens for the second time; then this error will happen...

Comment: In that case, I suspect you may have two columns with identical value 0 for causeClass. Can this be the case? In this case you need to have a surrogate key annotated with `@Id`, meaning add another field `@Id
private int;`

Comment: What happens is that i persist Table3 successfully the first time, but then i have to persist a new version of Table 3, and i want to overwrite all the existing values in Table 3, but when the compiler reads to the first CauseClass cell again and tries to persist it - it finds an existing 0 from my original Table 3, hope this clarifies a bit? Also that 0 value is correct - it is read in from the relevant table in excel

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Be sure you are using the good EntityManager's method to update existing entities. It seems that your trying to do a persist operation instead of a merge for existing entities.
When persisting antity, try to catch EntityExistsException or PersistenceException and in the catch block, call merge method.
For example :

```
save(Enity item){
    try{
        //Try to insert your entity by calling persist method    
    }
    catch(EntityExistsException e){
        //Entity you are trying to insert already exist, then call merge method
    }
}
```

Comment: Thats perfect cheers! That was the exact problem i had - i was calling persist when i should have been calling merger, Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

This error occurs when you try to update a domain object that already exists, like

```
User user=UserDao.getUserById(1);
session.save(user);
```

Hibernate will treat it like saving a new object and it will find that a duplicate object exists.

Before updating your object first load it from hibernate, like

```
User updatedUser=(User)session.load(User.class, 1);
updatedUser.setName("user name");
session.saveOrUpdate(updatedUser);
```